# Azure DevOps - OData REST API - Iterations - AnalyticsUpdatedDate does not gets updated with the IsEnded Flag?

Tags: azure-devops, iteration, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, I would like to query the Iterations ended by yesterday. AnalyticsUpdatedDate does not reflect the IsEnded timelines.

Since there is no ChangedDate / UpdatedDate column, trying to use the AnalyticsUpdatedDate in OData REST API. However the AnalyticsUpdatedDate does not reflect the IsEnded=true flagged date.
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam%20Fiber/_odata/v4.0-preview/Iterations

Is there a way to pull all the Iterations that are closed by yesterday?